# ValueError:ordinal must be <=1

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I was trying to check if the pyspark dataframe is empty using `df.rdd.isEmpty()` for performance.

I have to use this condition instead of using a COUNT() operation, as that was throwing an ordinal value error.

Does anyone has any suggestions for an approach to this?

Can you come up with feasible solutions?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the data in the dataframe?

Comment: `if df.limit(1).count() < 0`